# How can one earn interest on their EOS holdings?

Tags: chintai

Is there a way to generate more EOS from your eos holdings? I heard about chintai, but how does that work and how does one setup an chintai account to earn "interest" in eos? Are there other eos generating dapps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To earn interest with Chintai, go to https://eos.chintai.io.

Log in using [Scatter](https://get-scatter.com/).

Choose the market you want to lend on (7, 14, 21, or 28 day market).

In the order entry box, choose "LEND", and enter how much EOS you would like to lend, along with how much interest you would like to earn (use the Orderbook and Chart to figure out a reasonable interest rate).

Your order will be consumed as soon as the interest rate of your order is lower than the highest interest rate of a borrow order, you will receive the interest immediately, and your tokens will be locked for the duration of the market period, plus an additional 3-6 days for unstaking (this will be improved in a further version to reduce the unstaking to 3 days).

For more information on Chintai, check out the telegram chat https://t.me/ChintaiEOS

---

**Disclaimer: I wrote the Chintai smart contract.**

Comment: Do I release control of my coins to the chintai contract?

Comment: Yes, you have to transfer the tokens to the Chintai smart contract. This is in order to stop users from unstaking prematurely.

Comment: So there is the potential the smart contract can have a bug and everyone loses their EOS?

Comment: There is the potential (as always), however the only money that could be stolen would be the liquid EOS (open orders). If your order is fulfilled then the hacker would have to unstake the EOS in order to steal your money. As it stands, as long as you make sure that your order is fulfilled instantly, your money should be safe, because the moment it is finished unstaking it should be returned to you. The account also uses multisig from 11 BPs to protect against bad actors, exit scams, and someone managing to steal keys.